# Are second level cousins considered "Sapindas" in India's Hindu Marriage Act?

Tags: family-law, marriage, indian-constitutional-law, indian-penal-code, religious-law

Are second level cousins considered **[Sapindas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapinda)** in India's **[Hindu Marriage Act](https://highcourtchd.gov.in/hclscc/subpages/pdf_files/4.pdf)**?

Please refer the following screenshot in which the highlighted **SINDHUJA [Y]** (Red in color) and **RAJ [M1]** (White in color) may legally marry each other, but the **SANTHOS [M2]** (Blue in color) is considered **Sapindas** in India's **Hindu Marriage Act**.

Both **SINDHUJA [Y]** (Red in color) and **SANTHOS [M2]** (Blue in color) are close relationships, since obviously they are in a Sister and Brother relationship.

In this case, if the **SANTHOS [M2]** (Blue in color) tries to marry **SINDHUJA [Y]** (Red in color), is this relationship considered **Sapindas** in India's **Hindu Marriage Act**? In other words, can he legally marry her?

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to update the diagram with names, rather than colours.  Also, what do the arrows indicate?  Finally, what does "sibling brother" mean?  In (British) English, "brother" means "a male who shares at least one parent with another" (if being precise, "half-brother" is used if there is only one parent in common), "sibling" means exactly the same, except it applies to males and females equally.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica - I have updated the picture as requested

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica: The only thing I can think of is that Hindu law has different treatments/conditions for male/female persons? The labels are somewhat confusing me, seeing as e.g. Shalini is listed as Raj's sister, although she is also listed as daughter of the "sibling brother" of Raj's father Arjun, which is presumably makes her Raj's cousin, not sister? Unless this follows some sort of male "primogeniture" style rules, in which her exact relationship is irrelevant? E.g. all of these terms are translations or derived from not quite exact translations?